# Group by command not grouping my query results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Andddd I'm back! I'm trying to get the count of property sales in this db, and I've got it to sort out all the sales by town. Perfect. I put in a group by clause that SHOULD group them by what town they are in, but it is not. I'm sure its a stupid error, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
SELECT rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name, Count(town) as Town
FROM [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[PaymentList] pl inner join
 (Select agentID, min(first_name) as first_name, min(last_name) as last_name
  From [Intern_DB2]..[RealEstateAgentList]
  GROUP BY agentID, first_name, last_name
 ) rl
ON rl.AgentID = pl.AgentID
GROUP BY rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name, town;
```

I'm thinking my error is in the count command, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Not an error, just not getting the exact result I want. I'm getting it grouped the way I want (thank you again for that), I just want it to stop giving me multiple results for the same entry. I.E. Instead of saying oak beach has 3 sales, its showing oak beach 1 sale three times.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to remove `town` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name, Count(town) as Town
FROM [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[PaymentList] pl inner join
 (Select agentID, min(first_name) as first_name, min(last_name) as last_name
  From [Intern_DB2]..[RealEstateAgentList]
  GROUP BY agentID, first_name, last_name
 ) rl
ON rl.AgentID = pl.AgentID
GROUP BY rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name;
```

With `town` in the `group by`, you are counting the number of matches for an `agentid`/`town` combination.  So a given agent will be on multiple rows, one for each town.  It will then give the number of rows in `PaymentList` that are associated with that agent.

What do you want to do?  If you want to count the unique towns where an agent is, then do this:

```
SELECT rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name, Count(distinct town) as Town
FROM [INTERN_DB2].[dbo].[PaymentList] pl inner join
 (Select agentID, min(first_name) as first_name, min(last_name) as last_name
  From [Intern_DB2]..[RealEstateAgentList]
  GROUP BY agentID, first_name, last_name
 ) rl
ON rl.AgentID = pl.AgentID
GROUP BY rl.AgentID, rl.first_name, rl.last_name;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do! Thank you, I knew I was missing something. I tried the distinct modifier, but it didn't fix my problem. Should I do it as select distinct instead?